# cookie or session can not work on IIS Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5, session-cookies

I developed an Asp.Net application and published it on `IIS` on a `Windows 7 Professional`. 
Suddenly, people who view my web application from internet, started encountering with a problem which seem to prevent cookies or sessions being created. Basicly, cookies and sessions can not work or can not be created or destroyed immediately. 
My application has been on classic application pool on iis. 
What do you recommend me about this strange problem?

Comment: Users are people who connect the web site over the internet. I also encounter with the same issue if i try on local machine with localhost

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my problem on my own. The problem is very silly indeed. My web server was configured to use port `8080`. So i had to write the address as `localhost:8080` on my browser. 
I did some searches and i realised that `:` is a special character which causes the problem.  I read some people who uses special characters (like `_` etc.) in their address path faces the same issue on `IIS` on `Windows 7 Professional`